# PHP, alternate table row colors in while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to alternate row colours in a while loop. I have no idea why this code isn't working. It just shows the first row as black and all others as white. (I know the coding is a bit crappy, trying to learn as I build things) Any explanation on why it doesn't work is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
echo "<table border=1>";

$rows="0";
$bgcolor="black";

while($rows < 10) { 
    echo "<tr bgcolor=$bgcolor><td width=100> test </td> </tr>";
    $rows++;

    if ($bgcolor="black") $bgcolor="white";
    elseif ($bgcolor="white") $bgcolor="black";

}

echo"</table>";
```

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but the `border` and `bgcolor` attributes are deprecated and you should use CSS properties for this styling instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're doing an assignment in your `if` statements. You need to use the comparison operator (`==`) instead of the assignment (`=`)

Try replacing your if/elseif with this:

```
if ($bgcolor=="black") $bgcolor="white";
elseif ($bgcolor=="white") $bgcolor="black";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the if condition. You are using the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the equals operator (`==`), so the first condition always evaluates to true.

To work, the code needs to read:

```
if ($bgcolor=="black") $bgcolor="white";
elseif ($bgcolor=="white") $bgcolor="black";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

You already have a good answer that explains the problem you were having, but here are a couple of more condensed ways to set the alternating color with PHP if you're interested. Both depend on the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (`%`), which returns the remainder of a division. This is often useful for cyclic operations (like alternating colors.)

One way is to use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). `$rows++ % 2` will evaluate to either `1` or `0`, which will cause the ternary operator to yield either `'white'` or `'black'`.

```
$rows = 0;
while ($rows < 10) {
    $bgcolor = $rows++ % 2 ? 'white' : 'black';
    echo "<tr bgcolor=$bgcolor><td width=100> test </td></tr>";
}
```

Another way is to use the row number as an array index.

```
$rows = 0;
while ($rows < 10) {
    $bgcolor = ['black','white'][$rows++ % 2];
    echo "<tr bgcolor=$bgcolor><td width=100> test </td></tr>";
}
```

Here, the value of `$rows++ % 2` is used as an array index. This requires PHP >= 5.5, because `['black','white'][$rows++ % 2]` is dereferencing an array literal, which was not possible in earlier versions. You can still use this method in earlier versions; you just need to define the array in a separate statement (`$colors = array('black', 'white'); $bgcolor = $colors[$rows++ % 2];`).

This method can be useful if you want to cycle between more than two colors, e.g.:

```
$bgcolor = ['black','white','red'][$rows++ % 3];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll test those methods too. I'm on PHP 5.6 so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

easy way:

```
<style>
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
</style>
<?
$rows="0";
echo "<table border=1>";
while($rows < 10) {
echo "<tr><td width='100px'>test</td></tr>";
$rows++;
}
echo"</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if I can apply it.